# HTML Table - Loop through dynamically created rows and if field in specific column contains date prevent row from editing

Tags: javascript, html-table

I'm trying to create a JavaScript to disable a row if *EndDate* contains a date.
The table is generate automatically so I thought to lookup how many rows the table has and start iterating through them. Check if fields in column *EndDate* contain a date.
If that row contains a date then disable any field in that row.

To track down the fields I used this to check if I could disable them.

```
document.getElementById("r0_LineItemCode").disabled = "true";
document.getElementById("r0_LineItemCode_ref_ref").disabled = "true";
document.getElementById("pr0_LineItemCode").disabled = "true";
document.getElementById("r0_ec_type").disabled = "true";
```

> [image: Table]
>
> [image: Table code]
>
> [image: DateField]

I accomplished to loop through the rows and find out how many rows there are and show the data on the console.
But now selecting that field to check if it contains a date and then disable those row items  fails.

Code to track down the rows and iterate through the rows:

```
let text = "";
var endDateFields = [];
var rowData  = document.querySelector("#RequestLinesGrid_RowIDs");
console.log(rowData);
console.log(rowData.value);
const rows = rowData.value.split(',');

rows.forEach(myFunction);

console.log(text);
console.log(r0_EndDate);
console.log(r1_EndDate);
console.log(r2_EndDate);

function myFunction(item, index) {
  text += "indexNumber = " + index + " variableField: " + item + "_EndDate";

        var str = item + "_EndDate";
        eval(str);
        console.log(str);

}
```

I have the feeling I'm almost there, but need a little push in the right direction :)

Comment: Please don't post image of code, instead use tools `[<>]` into editor for create a complete snippet.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple logic of your problem, if `date` is not empty disable all `inputs` of the parent `tr`.

```js
document.querySelector('table').querySelectorAll('td.date').forEach(el => {
  if (el.innerHTML !== '') {
    const parentTr = el.parentElement;
    parentTr.querySelectorAll('input').forEach(input => {
      input.disabled = true;
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <th>id</th>
    <th>input1 Example</th>
    <th>input2 Example</th>
    <th>date Example</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td><input name='test' type='text'></td>
      <td><input name='test' type='text'></td>
      <td class='date'>10/10/2021</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td><input name='test' type='text'></td>
      <td><input name='test' type='text'></td>
      <td class='date'>10/10/2021</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td><input name='test' type='text'></td>
      <td><input name='test' type='text'></td>
      <td class='date'></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Instead of check all row just add a simple class on `td` have date then check it as my example.